Method causes ReflectionTypeLoadException in Assembly.GetTypes()
Update stream at bottom :)
I am using a Plugin architecture in a .net 8 application.  The plugins are loaded via:
PluginLoader.cs
public class PluginLoader
    {
        private List<ILmsPlugin> _plugins = new List<ILmsPlugin>();

        public PluginLoader(string[] pluginPaths)
        {
            _plugins = pluginPaths.SelectMany(pluginPath =>
            {
                Assembly pluginAssembly = LoadPlugin(pluginPath);
                return CreatePlugins(pluginAssembly);
            }).ToList();
        }

        public List<ILmsPlugin> GetPlugins() => _plugins;

        private static Assembly LoadPlugin(string relativePath)
        {
            // Navigate up to the solution root
            string root = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(
                            Path.GetDirectoryName(
                                Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location)))))));

            string pluginLocation = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(root, relativePath.Replace('\\', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));

            var loadContext = new PluginLoadContext(pluginLocation);
            return loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(new AssemblyName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pluginLocation)));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<ILmsPlugin> CreatePlugins(Assembly assembly)
        {
            int count = 0;
            // EXCEPTION IS HERE
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (typeof(ILmsPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                {
                    ILmsPlugin result = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ILmsPlugin;
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        count++;
                        yield return result;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count == 0)
            {
                string availableTypes = string.Join(",", assembly.GetTypes().Select(t => t.FullName));
                throw new ApplicationException(
                    $"Can't find any type which implements ILmsPlugin in {assembly} from {assembly.Location}.\n" +
                    $"Available types: {availableTypes}");
            }
        }
    }


The interface for the plugins is like this:
ILmsPlugin.cs
public interface ILmsPlugin
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public string MachineName { get; }

        public Type ConfigurationClass { get; }

        public void SetConfiguration(string configuration);

        public Task<ILmsPluginQuizOutputDto> CreateQuiz(Quiz quiz);

        public ILmsPluginInstanceConfiguration? GetConfiguration();
    }

And a concrete class:

public class LmsPlugin : ILmsPlugin
    {
        private ILmsPluginInstanceConfiguration? Configuration { get; set; }

        public string Name { get => "Mock LmsPlugin"; }

        public string MachineName { get => "mock_lmsplugin"; }

        public Type ConfigurationClass { get => typeof(MockLmsPluginConfiguration); }

        public Task<ILmsPluginQuizOutputDto> CreateQuiz(Quiz quiz)
        {
            ILmsPluginQuizOutputDto dto = new LmsPluginQuizOutput
            {
                Name = quiz.Name,
                CourseId = 1
            };

            return Task.FromResult(dto);
        }

        public void SetConfiguration(string? configuration)
        {
            if (configuration == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Configuration = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(configuration, ConfigurationClass) as ILmsPluginInstanceConfiguration;
        }

        public ILmsPluginInstanceConfiguration? GetConfiguration()
        {
            return Configuration;
        }
    }


This is the error:
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Method 'CreateQuiz' in type 'MockLmsPlugin.LmsPlugin' from assembly 'MockLmsPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at LmsPluginManager.PluginLoader.CreatePlugins(Assembly assembly)+MoveNext() in /Users/[removed]/Sites/[r]]/[r]]/LmsPluginManager/PluginLoader.cs:line 41
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.ToList()
   at LmsPluginManager.PluginLoader..ctor(String[] pluginPaths) in /Users/[removed]/Sites/[r]]/[r]]/LmsPluginManager/PluginLoader.cs:line 12
   at Tests.UnitTests.PluginManagerTests.PluginManagerTest.PluginIsAvailableInContainer() in /Users/[removed]/Sites/[r]]/[r]]/Tests/UnitTests/Plugins/PluginManagerTests.cs:line 18
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

Updates

I have removed the abstract class because, after removing it from my codebase and implementing the interface directly I continue to get the same error; therefore, this error isn't related to abstract methods.  The code has been updated to reflect the directly implementation and I've confirmed the same error continues to happen.

I confirmed that if I remove the method from the interface the application works as expected - it's only when I add the createQuiz method does the error happen.

Because this is a plugin architecture, I understand it's important to ensure .dll files of the plugins are not copied to other assemblies.  I have confirmed this is not happening:



Per the instructions found here I have configured my .csproj files for the plugins:
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\[removed].LmsPluginBase\[removed].LmsPluginBase.csproj" >
      **<Private>false</Private>**
      **<ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>**
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\[removed].Core\[removed].Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\[removed].ServiceModels\[removed].ServiceModels.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    **<EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>**
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

At least 1 method does work, here I can see that GetConfiguration returns as expected:

I modified the method, did a dotnet clean && dotnet rebuild and ran the tests again, I get the expected result:


In order to see if it had something to do with what Ivan mentioned in comments I did a quick test.  I edited my interface to add a new method and remove the CreateQuiz method.  Then I implemented the new method, dotnet clean && dotnet rebuild and reran the integration test - the new method is found/loaded correctly:



so the abstract and the implementation class are "mocks". Could it be that the code is trying to intantiate an instance of the abstract class? ILmsPlugin result = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ILmsPlugin;

Neither are mocks in the Moq sense. The MockLmsPlugin is a full implementation that I named this way because it doesn't interact with 3rd party systems and is the only plugin that gets loaded in test startup. BaseLmsPlugin is intended to be used by all implementations.

You may be correct that it's trying to instantiate the abstract class.  If so, the error message is misleading and I'm still not sure how to get past it.  I dont have access to IsAbstract at the point of exception (that I know of)

yeah, I was more implying "fakes" or whatever the correct term is. Question 1 is in which assemblies do the interface, the abstract class and the concrete implementation live? Maybe I am misreading it but I what I gather is that the abstract class and the interface live together and the concrete implementation is in a separate assembly.

You're correct that the interface and abstract are in one assembly.  Every implementation live in distinct assemblies

are you still getting the same exact error message?

Yes.  In case you missed it, I confirmed that another method, GetConfiguration, works just fine :/

have you checked this I think there might be hints if not right-away solutions

specifically "This can happen if you add a method to an interface in one assembly, and then to an implementing class in another assembly, but you rebuild the implementing assembly without referencing the new version of the interface assembly." from the top answer

The quick check was to delete all /bin and /obj folders - I did that with no luck; I'll move onto the other steps.  I did test adding a new method to the interface and that worked correctly.   It's probably worth mentioning that ILmsPluginQuizOutputDto and ILmsPluginInstanceConfiguration are in the same namespace, so it's not an issue there.

Seems as if I've narrowed it down to the Quiz quiz argument.  I took the CreateQuiz method down to just no arguments, returning a string, and when I added back in the Quiz argument the error surfaces.  I think that this suggests something with the project that defines that model, ServiceModels.  Maybe it's getting loaded multiple times, so they aren't actually equal.

@IvanPetrov that was it - the Plugin projects were including the ServicesModel incorrectly.  I needed to do this:
<ProjectReference Include="..\[removed].ServiceModels\[removed].ServiceModels.csproj" >       <Private>false</Private>       <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>     </ProjectReference>
The important part being the Private and ExcludeAssets (which I had for the PluginBase project, but not the models :/

glad that you figured it out. I'd write/accept this solution as an answer if I were you.

The root cause of this was that the interface and concrete class methods were using different versions of the ServiceModels.Quizzes.Quiz class - which was very hard to tell.  Ultimately it was tracked down by decomposing the method into a very simple form, and then slowly building it back up until the error was reproduced.
This is resolved by ensuring the .dll's of shared projects are not copied to the output directory.  This is outlined here, specifically:

In between the  tags, add the following elements:

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PluginBase\PluginBase.csproj">
        <Private>false</Private>
        <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>


The false element is important. This tells MSBuild to not copy PluginBase.dll to the output directory for HelloPlugin. If the PluginBase.dll assembly is present in the output directory, PluginLoadContext will find the assembly there and load it when it loads the HelloPlugin.dll assembly. At this point, the HelloPlugin.HelloCommand type will implement the ICommand interface from the PluginBase.dll in the output directory of the HelloPlugin project, not the ICommand interface that is loaded into the default load context. Since the runtime sees these two types as different types from different assemblies, the AppWithPlugin.Program.CreateCommands method won't find the commands. As a result, the false metadata is required for the reference to the assembly containing the plugin interfaces.

While I did this for the Plugin projects themselves, e.g.
<ProjectReference Include="..\[].LmsPluginBase\[].LmsPluginBase.csproj" >
      <Private>false</Private>
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>

I did not do it for a project that is shared, so within any projects that:

Have interfaces or classes used that will be used via reflection
Use shared projects (e.g. classlibs)

You must make sure they do not copy the dlls of the shared projects to the output directory, e.g.
<ProjectReference Include="..\[].ServiceModels\[].ServiceModels.csproj" >
      <Private>false</Private>
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>

